# Перекрытие элементов WinForm

Tags: winforms

Как установить последовательность перекрытие элементов (z-индекс) WinForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя - [Control.BringToFront](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront?view=netcore-3.1) и [Control.SendToBack](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback?view=netcore-3.1).